# The old-money rich "don't buy their own furniture?"

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

I've heard it said of the old-money wealthy that they "don't buy their own furniture."

Is the implication that the family has so many heirlooms, and perhaps of superior quality to modern goods, that they furnish with family heirlooms?  Or that they hire designers to furnish their quarters?  Or something else?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard the saying.  It's likely fairly rare, and possibly limited to certain subcultures.

Comment: I don't recall hearing it often, and perhaps only once?  Even if it was a one-off I'm wondering what the most likely meaning was, of course.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean that the furniture was either inherited or "gifted".

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic on ELU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They inherit it. The Economist says "Being the sort of person who 'buys his own furniture', a remark that Alan Clark, a former minister and diarist once reported as directed at Michael Heseltine, a self-made Tory colleague, is still worthy of note in circles where most inherit it." Clark was the son of a successful art historian and gallerist, [Kenneth Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Clark) who himself came from a wealthy background.

"But did they buy their own furniture?" The Economist, 10 August 2006, https://www.economist.com/britain/2006/08/10/but-did-they-buy-their-own-furniture

(Apologies if this isn't terribly on-topic but I couldn't recommend where to move it.)

Comment: Many thanks, and as I've read the Economist cover to cover since 1994, that must be where I saw the phrase!  Only took me 14 years of wondering about it before I decided to inquire!